# Response time of solr instance with shards and no shards

Tags: solr, solrcloud

When I test my solr instance, it turns out instance with no shard has a shorter response time than instance with shards. So, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically because, in solrcloud mode, your query will first need to be sent out to all the nodes involved. All the nodes will then return the results to the original node that was queried, which will then collate the results and return them to you. The overhead of distributing the requests and collating the results is what increases the response time.

This is in contrast with standalone mode, where only one server will be queried and will return the response.

See the documentation [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Distributed+Requests) for details.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like that `http` requests cost much time.